Integration in Minkowski spacetime
Consider a scalar field
$$\phi \equiv \phi(r) = \frac{a}{r}$$
in Minkowski spacetime $\mathbb{M}$ in usual spherical coordinates. The field satisfies
$$\nabla^{\mu} \nabla_{\mu} \phi = 0$$
Now this leads to
$$0 = \int_{\mathbb{M}} dV \ \phi \cdot \nabla_{\mu} \nabla^{\mu} \phi = \int_{\mathbb{M}} dV \ \nabla_{\mu} \big( \phi \cdot \nabla^{\mu} \phi \big) - \int_{\mathbb{M}} dV \ \nabla_{\mu} \phi \nabla^{\mu} \phi \tag{1}$$
The first integral may be transformed to a „boundary integral“
$$\int_{\mathbb{M}} dV \ \nabla_{\mu} \big( \phi \cdot \nabla^{\mu} \phi \big) = - \lim_{r -> \infty} 4\pi \int dt \ r^2 \frac{a}{r} \frac{a}{r^2} = 0$$
The second integral is
$$\int_{\mathbb{M}} dV \ \nabla_{\mu} \phi \nabla^{\mu} \phi = 4\pi \int dt \int_0^{\infty} dr \ r^2 \ \frac{a}{r^2} \frac{a}{r^2} = - 4\pi a^2 \int dt \Big[ \frac{1}{r} \Big]_0^{\infty}$$
Which diverges! So equation (1) is
$$0 = 0 - \infty$$
What is going wrong here?

I think your second equation should be something like $\Delta \phi \propto \delta^{(3)}(x)$, since your field does not depend on time, and because this proportionality is well known (see here)

Hm, I see. However, the equation $\nabla_{\mu} \nabla^{\mu} \phi = 0$ is actually the requirement I want the field to satisfy. The solution $\phi = a/r$ was just an example of a field satisfying this equation (or so I thought) that I came up with. So if I understand you correctly, this field is in fact no solution as it does not satisfy the equation at the origin? And so the integral does not equal 0 but rather equal $\phi(0)$?

Yes, that's right. For a general solution to the massless wave equation, you can use a Fourier decomposition in four dimensions.
